# How to convert this curl example to google apps script / javascript?

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, curl, urlfetch

So I'm sitting down with trying to make some buttons that activate timers in toggl. My problem is that I'm unsure how to convert the curl example they give into a working javascript UrlFetchApp.

Just at the authentication phase right now. The Toggl documentation says that this format is username:password (I know the use of the word secret as the password is confusing)

```
curl -v -u john.doe@gmail.com:secret -X GET https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/me
```

My attempts were (resulted in 403 error):

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/me');
```

And (resulted in 405 error):

```
function stepTwo(){
  // Make a POST request with form data.
var formData = {
  'username': 'myemail@gmail.com',
  'password': 'mypassword',
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/me', options);
}
```

Comment: The example use GET method but your second code use 'post' method... try replacing it by 'get'

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/toggl_api.md#authentication) Toogl uses Basic Auth (aka. OAuth0). Check out this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on how to authenticate using Basic Auth.